# Split elements in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a big array and a part of that is shown in small example below.
in each list, the first number is start and the 2nd number is end
(so there is a range) but each element is a part of a sequence and
each sequence starts from zero.
. what I want to do is:

small example:

```
array([[ 469, 1300],
       [ 171, 1440],
       [ 187, 1564],
       [ 204, 1740],
       [  40, 1363],
       [  56, 1457],
       [ 132,  606],
       [1175, 2096],
       [ 484, 2839],
       [ 132, 4572],
       [ 166, 1693],
       [  69, 3300],
       [ 142, 1003],
       [2118, 2118],
       [ 715, 1687],
       [ 301, 1006],
       [  48, 2142],
       [  63,  330],
       [ 479, 2411]], dtype=uint32)
```

I want to take from the begining of each sequence which is indexed 0
(not included in the ranges) until -20 before
the start of each range.

I tried this code:

```
cds = np.column_stack([cdspos[:, 0] - cdspos[:, 0], cdspos[:, 0] - 20])
```

but it gives this error:

```
    y = _nx.arange(0, num, dtype=dt)
 MemoryError
```

but I try this one:

```
cds = np.column_stack([cdspos[:, 0] - 100, cdspos[:, 0] - 20])
```

it works perfectly. the problem is that I don't have the same range
before the starting point (all of them are not 100).

so, I want to get a smaller ranges (lists) like this: (0) to
(start-20). for example the first element would be like this:

```
[ 0, 449]
```

I also tried

```
cds = np.column_stack([0, cdspos[:, 0] - 20])
```

but did not work.

for the small example, the output I am looking for would be like this:

```
array([[0, 449],
       [0, 151],
       [0, 167],
       [0, 184],
       [0, 20],
       [0, 36],
       [0,  112],
       [0, 1155],
       [0, 464],
       [0, 112],
       [0, 146],
       [0, 49],
       [0, 122],
       [0, 2098],
       [0, 695],
       [0, 281],
       [0, 28],
       [0,  43],
       [0, 459]], dtype=uint32)
```

do you guys know how to do that?

Comment: I tried this and worked perfectly: cds1 = np.column_stack([np.zeros(len(cdspos), dtype="uint32") , cdspos[:, 1]])

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
In [22]: np.column_stack((np.zeros(a.shape[0], dtype=np.int8), (a[:,0]- 20).astype(np.int16)))
Out[22]: 
array([[   0,  449],
       [   0,  151],
       [   0,  167],
       [   0,  184],
       [   0,   20],
       [   0,   36],
       [   0,  112],
       [   0, 1155],
       [   0,  464],
       [   0,  112],
       [   0,  146],
       [   0,   49],
       [   0,  122],
       [   0, 2098],
       [   0,  695],
       [   0,  281],
       [   0,   28],
       [   0,   43],
       [   0,  459]], dtype=int16)
```

Note that in this case I used `np.int8` for zeros and `np.int16` (or use `np.uint32` if your numbers are larger to be fit on `int16`)for second column numbers. If you get memory error again this means that you can't preserve your arrays at once in your RAM. You can divide your array to multiple parts and apply the operations on different parts separately and process them separately too. If this is not possible

Comment: again i got this error:       y = _nx.arange(0, num, dtype=dt)
MemoryError

Comment: @user3631908 In that case you can specify the types manually I think it will helps. Try the update.

Comment: now the error is: ValueError: Number of samples, -1, must be non-negative.

Comment: @user3631908 I think your numbers are greater to fit on `int16` so use `int32` instead.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
In [17]: numpy.array([[0, start -20] for start, end in a], dtype=numpy.uint32)
Out[17]: 
array([[   0,  449],
   [   0,  151],
   [   0,  167],
   [   0,  184],
   [   0,   20],
   [   0,   36],
   [   0,  112],
   [   0, 1155],
   [   0,  464],
   [   0,  112],
   [   0,  146],
   [   0,   49],
   [   0,  122],
   [   0, 2098],
   [   0,  695],
   [   0,  281],
   [   0,   28],
   [   0,   43],
   [   0,  459]], dtype=uint32)
```

Comment: @ log0: the same error:  y = _nx.arange(0, num, dtype=dt)
MemoryError
>>>

Comment: How big is your original array ?

Comment: it is about 20000

Comment: I looks like you are running out of memory. 20000 lines is fairly small (about 160kb), another part of your program must be leaking memory. Did you check the memory consumption ?